# Установить open_basedir в .htaccess

Tags: apache, php

Здравствуйте.

Скажите вот мое дерево папок:

C:\www\htdocs\  - корень веб сервера

C:\www\htdocs\14\ - корень сайта

Как мне поставить ограничение open_basedir чтобы скрипты из 14/ наружу никак не могли обратиться.

Надо мне, например, когда "чужой какой то сайт или скрипт"  у себя на локалке изучаю, мало ли там вредоносный код, чтобы не попортило мне систему.

Проверяю таким кодом(в 14\index.php):

```
include './xxx.php'; // из текущей папки должно успешно  отработать
include '../12/yyy.php';  // вот это получается не должно отработать, выдать ошибку
```

В .htaccess(который в папке 14/) пробовал так:

```
php_value open_basedir "C:/WWW/htdocs/14/"
```

и так:

```
php_value open_basedir "/"
```

Ограничение не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вообще таким образом вы ограничиваете зону открытия файлов, думаю посмотрите, что выдает __DIR__ и впишите это значение. Слэш обратный или прямой - по разному интерпритируются. Кроме того решать проблемы безопасности на уровне настроек php очень неправильно.

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) выдает "C:\WWW\htdocs\14". Сменил на него. Ограничение все равно не работает.
Что значит неправильно? А как правильно? Я описал что мне надо.

 На хостингах бывает стоит такое ограничение(open_basedir) и не дает обращаться к файлам извне. Вот также хочу настроить на локалке.

Comment: Отлично, хостинги с таким ограничением скорее всего бесплатные. Но вопрос не в том. Укажите пожалуйста где вы устанавливаете это ограничение. В каком файле и как. Спрашиваю т.к. это можно вписать чуть ли не в 5и местах. И устанавливается оно по разному и в некоторых местах просто не рабоает.

Comment: В первом сообщении я указал что в .htaccess пишу это ограничение.

Comment: можно изменить только в php.ini или в httpd.conf (в настройках виртуального сервера) и то нало устанавливать так:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /htdocs/>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "C:/htdocs/"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Изменил на как вы советуете, апач не грузится, ошибку пишет:

    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName www.somesite.ru
    DocumentRoot "C:/WWW/htdocs/13"
    <Directory /htdocs/13> php_admin_value open_basedir "C:/htdocs/13" </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

Странно что еще пишет же Changeable = PHP_INI_ALL

Comment: вы то хоть понимаете, что изменили для како-го то сайта www.somesite.ru который просто идет в примере? Вам нудно для вашего и у апача есть логи, что они говорят?

Comment: Во вы даете. www.somesite.ru - это виртуальный адрес. Чтобы я на локалке мог устанавливать сайты из под корня. Если вы таких вещей не понимаете, то понятно почему ваши ответы идут тупо как наугад.

Хоть бы проверяли сначала...

Comment: :) я уверен что open_basedir можно установить только в апаче и php.ini если ответ не понравился формулировкой то это ваше личное.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вышло:

```
<Directory "C:/WWW/htdocs/14">
php_admin_value open_basedir "C:/WWW/htdocs/14"
</Directory>
```

Это отдельно от виртуального хоста прописал в httpd.conf

Answer (score -1):

`php_value open_basedir "."` просто в .htaccess напиши так и будет тебе счастье:)

Comment: это вредный совет, подобного рода вещи резко снижают безопасность веб-сервера. Даже в 2013 году подобное советовать было моветон, а уж в 2018 - подавно. Кстати, на so не очень приветствуется давать дубликаты ответов - а у вас ответ ничем не отличается от данных ранее и это не списать на "мы одновременно писали, я не видел".